# pre allocation for struct ,matlab

Tags: matlab

pre allocation of struct in matlab is a problem.
Please see following code in matlab profiler

```
      time   calls  line

                2    65 sizeofTLS= 10000;
    < 0.01       2   66 LaserS(sizeofTLS).POI(n)={0}; 
      0.03       2   67 LaserS(sizeofTLS).dis(n)={0}; 
      0.04       2   68 LaserS(sizeofTLS).plane(n)={0}; 
                     69 
                     70 
    < 0.01       2   71 for it=1:sizeofTLS 
     16.74 2823212   72     LaserS(it).POI(1:n)={0}; 
     16.91 2823212   73     LaserS(it).dis(1:n)={0}; 
     16.88 2823212   74     LaserS(it).plane(1:n)={0}; 
      1.04 2823212   75 end
```

How can I improve it(72,73,74)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to preallocate structs is with the following syntax:

```
myEmptyCell = num2cell( zeros(1,n) );
b           = repmat( struct('POI', myEmptyCell ,...
                             'dis', myEmptyCell,...
                             'plane', myEmptyCell ) , sizeofTLS, 1 );
```

This is ~10x faster than not preallocating on my laptop.